# Unable to find exact source code of my blog

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am into a project where I deal with parsing HTML of web pages. So, I took my [blog](http://withmycam.blogspot.com) (Bloggers Blog - Dynamic Template) and tried to read the content of it. Unfortunately I failed to look at "actual" source of the blog's webpage.

Here is what I observed:

1. I clicked `view source` on a random article of my blog and tried to find the content in it. and I couldn't find any. It was all JavaScript.
2. So, I saved the webpage to my laptop and checked the source again, this time I found the content.
3. I also checked the source using `developers tools` in browsers and again found the content in it.
4. Now, I tried the python way

   ```
   import urllib
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   soup = BeautifulSoup( urllib.urlopen("my-webpage-address") )
   print soup.prettify()
   ```

   I even didn't find the content in the HTML code in it.

Finally, why I am unable to find the content in the source code in case1, 4.

How should I get the actual HTML code? I wish to hear any python library that would do the job.

Comment: You have to parse the JavaScript, which has other implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is loaded via JavaScript (AJAX). It's not in the "source".

In step 2, you are saving the *resulting* page, not the original source.  In step 3, you're seeing what's being rendered by the browser.

Steps 1 and 4 "don't work" because you're getting the page's source (which doesn't contain the content).  You need to actually run the JavaScript, which isn't easy for a screen scraper to do.

Comment: So, how should I exactly extract the content I write in it?

Comment: @Surya: you would need to search for a "headless browser" framework or lib that can render the page exactly like a browser would, including javascript. Phantomjs, or ghost or casperjs

Comment: Or, if you are okay with just having the raw content, you can make the ajax requests in Python yourself by hitting the ajax endpoint with the appropriate get or post data.